# Does Selenium Web Driver Support Browser Pop-ups in Headless Mode?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless

Does Selenium Web Driver Support Browser Pop-ups in Headless Mode? Or is there a workaround to proceed with actions involving browser pop-ups when running in headless mode?

Comment: are you talking about javascript pop ups?

Comment: @pArAs Yes, that's the most common scenario.

Comment: Can you add example image with popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `headless browser` to work on `Javascript popups` you may want to launch it by enabling javascript in `Desired Capabilities`

You can use something like below:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = cap.merge(DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs());
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(cap);
```

Hope it helps.